# How to take a screenshot of the X virtual framebuffer display?

Tags: osx, screenshot, xvfb

I would like to take a screenshot from Xvfb display server.

I already tried:

```
xwd -root -silent -out screen.xwd
```

but I can't read this file and I couldn't find any software (via Homebrew) which can display or convert it.

Is there any better way of doing that on OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netpbm (`brew install netpbm`) can process xwd files, so you should be able to do the standard Unix X11 process:

```
$ xwd -root -silent -out screen.xwd
$ xwdtopnm < screen.xwd | pnmtojpeg > screen.jpg
xwdtopnm: writing PPM file
```

Comment: I've `pnmtojpeg` missing, how to install it?

Comment: It should be part of netpbm; hmm, I don't compile from source - maybe you need to pass additional flags

Comment: Ok, it seems it is there (`brew list netpbm | grep pnmtojpeg`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems using `import` command from ImageMagick package is much easier, for example:

```
import -window root screen.jpeg
```

However when installing imagemagick, it needs to be compiled with X11, e.g.

```
brew install imagemagick --with-x11
```